# Is an empty `<OrganizationURL />` within a Federation Metadata XML file considered invalid?

Tags: saml

I have an IdP who produces metadata federation XML files where the `<OrganizationURL />` element is empty. See the example below:

```
<Organization>
    <OrganizationName xml:lang="en">Example Co</OrganizationName>
    <OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">Example Co Limited</OrganizationDisplayName>
    <OrganizationURL xml:lang="en"/>
</Organization>
```

I've had more than one SaaS provider reject the federation metadata XML file because of this. In each instance I've just removed the `<Organization />` since it is optional.

That said, does anyone know whether an empty `<OrganizationURL />` is considered invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's invalid. The Metadata for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0 specification includes the following XML schema definition:

```
<element name="OrganizationURL" type="md:localizedURIType"/>
```

It needs to be a URI.